# How to get Devise scopes to send the correct confirmation e-mail template?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes, scopes

I'm trying to use Devise with multiple scopes without overriding the 
Devise controllers until I absolutely have to.  I think I may have 
reached a point to where I finally will have to override the 
controllers.

I have three different portals/scopes called faculty, 
professor, and student and they all use the user devise model.  Each 
one of these scopes has their own devise views and custom sign in 
templates.

The issue I am having is I get the same confirmation e- 
mail template regardless of the scope I'm signed in.  The one I keep 
getting is the first one defined in my routes.rb file.  For example:

```
 devise_for :students, :class_name => 'User', 
    :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out =>'logout', :sign_up => 'signup' } 
 resources :students

 devise_for :faculty, :class_name => 'User', 
    :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out =>'logout', :sign_up => 'signup' } 
 resources :faculty 

 devise_for :professors, :class_name => 'User', 
     :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out =>'logout', :sign_up => 'signup' } 
 resources :professors 

 devise_for :users, 
     :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout',:sign_up => 'signup' } 
 resources :users
```

Every time I get a confirmation e-mail it will use the student 
confirmation email template.  If I move faculty to the top, I'll get 
the faculty email and so on.

Is there a way to get each scope to send 
their respective confirmation e-mail template without having to 
override Devise?